# localhost:3000 not working even though I have followed the tutorial correctly?

Tags: localhost, sanity

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO7_jgzVgbc) at the moment to learn how to connect my project to my Sanity backend. I need to do localhost:3000 but it isn't working and everything I have tried so far to fix it hasn't worked. I don't know enough about this.

Error: This site can't be reached; localhost refused to connect; ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I have https://localhost:3000 in my CORS origin in my Sanity project API settings.

This is my configuration:

```
"type": "pwa-chrome",
"request": "launch",
"name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
"url": "http://localhost:3000",
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

I'm not sure what other information I can give to help, let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, turns out I hadn't actually created a react app yet.